# Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} dx$

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1-\frac{\cos^3(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 1-\frac{1}{1+\tan^3(x)} dx$$

Then to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{1+\tan^3(x)}dx$, I let $\tan(x)=t$ and hence $dt = \sec^2(x) dx$, which implies $dx=\frac{1}{\sec^2(x)}dt$.

Then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: LaTex tip: if you type \ before sin and cosine it looks better. Compare $sin x$ vs $\sin x$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replacing $x$ by $\pi/2-x$, the integral becomes
$$ I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\cos^3{x}}{\cos^3{x}+\sin^3{x}} \, dx. $$
Adding together with the original form of $I$,
$$ 2I = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin^3{x}+\cos^3{x}}{\cos^3{x}+\sin^3{x}} \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} 1 \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2}, $$
so $I = \pi/4$.

This trick works on any integral of the form
$$ \int_0^a \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(a-x)} \, dx: $$
the answer is always $a/2$.

Comment: wow! very clever :-)

Comment: Beat me to it...

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=\frac{\pi}2-u$. Then $dx=-du$ and the integral becomes:

$$I=-\int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{\sin^3(\pi/2-u)}{\sin^3(\pi/2-u)+\cos^3(\pi/2-u)}du\\=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^3(u)}{\cos^3 (u)+\sin^3(u)}du$$

So your integral satisfies:

$$2I=\int_0^{\pi/2} 1dx=\frac{\pi}2$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^3(x)}{\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)} dx$ ......(1)

Using property -

$\int_a^{b} f(x) dx = \int_a^{b} f(a + b - x) dx$

We have,

$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^3(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{\cos^3(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)+\sin^3(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)} dx$

$I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos^3(x)}{\sin^3(x)+\cos^3(x)} dx$ .....(2)

Adding equation (1) and (2),

$2I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} dx$

$2I = \left[x\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

$2I = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$I = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Is $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$ always true for any $f(x),a,b$?

Comment: No, most of the time its work. Sometimes you have to use other properties. You have to see other properties as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is from Wolfram-alpha]

I entered this into Wolfram alpha and this is what it gives me.

Comment: That looks fun.

Comment: This is a classic example of why it's better to think before you integrate...

Comment: Disagree, clearly wolfram has a more elegant method.

Comment: You know, I'm tempted to upvote this answer because it IS indeed useful...for showing what NOT to do. :)

Comment: @ZacharySelk exactly XD this has to be the most long-winded solution possible

Comment: One of my professors once complimented me: "I admire your ability to take a math problem and wrestle it to the ground and strangle it with your bare hands."  Nice to meet a kindred spirit here!
So OK, the substitution of $\pi/2 -x$ is indeed very cute and amazing. But what if the problem had  different limits of integration, say  $\pi/4$ to $3\pi/2$ or some such. You need to be able t wrestle with it a bit. Good stuff.